# How to use NodeJS command line in Console2 in windows?

Tags: console2

How we can use Nodejs command line in [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/)?

Comment: Answer: Created a new tab in console2 settings, shell: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k &quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat&quot;`

The address of `nodevars.bat` file maybe different in your windows.

Comment: If you ask a question and later find a solution to that yourself, just write it down as answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: For the people marking to close, this is a pretty straight forward question that fits into the scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created a new tab in console2 settings, shell: `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k &quot;C:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat&quot;` The address of `nodevars.bat` file maybe different in your windows.